# How to compile c++ with emsdk if i use ITK?

Tags: c++, cmake, webassembly, emscripten, itk

I am trying to compile C++ code with emscripten. First I try to build ITK. I clone the repository: `git clone https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK.git`.

And I enter: `cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake`.
But I get the error:

```
CMake Error at Modules/ThirdParty/ZLIB/src/itkzlib-ng/CMakeLists.txt:466 (message):
  sizeof(void *) is neither 32 nor 64 bit
```

Emscripten version 3.1.34.

Tell me, please, what's the matter?

Here logs:

```
C:\itknew\ITK\build>cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cmake\Modules\Platform\Emscripten.cmake
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.39.2.windows.1")
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-uninitialized
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-uninitialized - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-unused-parameter
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-unused-parameter - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wall
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wall - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-long-double
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-long-double - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wcast-align
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wcast-align - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wdisabled-optimization
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wdisabled-optimization - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wextra
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wextra - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wformat_2
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wformat_2 - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Winvalid-pch
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Winvalid-pch - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-format-nonliteral
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-format-nonliteral - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wpointer-arith
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wpointer-arith - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wshadow
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wshadow - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wunused
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wunused - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wwrite-strings
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wwrite-strings - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-funit-at-a-time
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-funit-at-a-time - Failed
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-strict-overflow
-- Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-strict-overflow - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wall
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wall - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-long-double
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-long-double - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wcast-align
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wcast-align - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wdisabled-optimization
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wdisabled-optimization - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wextra
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wextra - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wformat_2
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wformat_2 - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Winvalid-pch
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Winvalid-pch - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-format-nonliteral
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-format-nonliteral - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wpointer-arith
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wpointer-arith - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wshadow
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wshadow - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wunused
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wunused - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wwrite-strings
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wwrite-strings - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-funit-at-a-time
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-funit-at-a-time - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-strict-overflow
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-strict-overflow - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-deprecated
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-deprecated - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-invalid-offsetof
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-invalid-offsetof - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-undefined-var-template
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wno-undefined-var-template - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Woverloaded-virtual
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Woverloaded-virtual - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wstrict-null-sentinel
-- Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wstrict-null-sentinel - Failed
-- Found Python3: C:/Users/Aleksandr.HOME-PC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe (found suitable version "3.11.2", minimum required is "3.7") found components: Interpreter
-- Running module dependency checks
-- Enabled ITKAnisotropicSmoothing, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKAntiAlias, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKBiasCorrection, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKBinaryMathematicalMorphology, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKClassifiers, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKColormap, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKCommon, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKConnectedComponents, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKConvolution, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKCurvatureFlow, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKDICOMParser, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKDeconvolution, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKDeformableMesh, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKDenoising, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKDiffusionTensorImage, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKDisplacementField, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKDistanceMap, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKDoubleConversion, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKEigen, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKEigen3, needed by [ITKCommon].
-- Enabled ITKExpat, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKFFT, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKFastMarching, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKFiniteDifference, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGDCM, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGIFTI, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGPUAnisotropicSmoothing, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGPUCommon, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGPUFiniteDifference, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGPUImageFilterBase, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGPUPDEDeformableRegistration, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGPURegistrationCommon, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGPUSmoothing, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGPUThresholding, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKGoogleTest, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKHDF5, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOBMP, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOBioRad, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOBruker, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOCSV, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOGDCM, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOGE, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOGIPL, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOHDF5, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOIPL, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOImageBase, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOJPEG, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOJPEG2000, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOLSM, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMINC, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMRC, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMesh, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMeshBYU, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMeshBase, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMeshFreeSurfer, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMeshGifti, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMeshOBJ, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMeshOFF, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMeshVTK, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOMeta, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIONIFTI, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIONRRD, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOPNG, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIORAW, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOSiemens, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOSpatialObjects, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOStimulate, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOTIFF, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOTransformBase, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOTransformHDF5, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOTransformInsightLegacy, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOTransformMatlab, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOVTK, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIOXML, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageAdaptors, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageCompare, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageCompose, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageFeature, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageFilterBase, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageFrequency, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageFunction, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageFusion, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageGradient, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageGrid, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageIntensity, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageLabel, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageNoise, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageSources, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKImageStatistics, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKIntegratedTest, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKJPEG, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKKLMRegionGrowing, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKKWSys, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKLIBLBFGS, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKLabelMap, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKLabelVoting, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKLevelSets, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKLevelSetsv4, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKMINC, needed by [ITKIOMINC].
-- Enabled ITKMarkovRandomFieldsClassifiers, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKMathematicalMorphology, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKMesh, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKMetaIO, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKMetricsv4, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKNIFTI, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKNarrowBand, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKNetlib, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKNrrdIO, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKOpenJPEG, needed by [ITKIOJPEG2000].
-- Enabled ITKOptimizers, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKOptimizersv4, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKPDEDeformableRegistration, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKPNG, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKPath, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKPolynomials, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKQuadEdgeMesh, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKQuadEdgeMeshFiltering, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKRegionGrowing, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKRegistrationCommon, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKRegistrationMethodsv4, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKSignedDistanceFunction, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKSmoothing, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKSpatialFunction, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKSpatialObjects, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKStatistics, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKSuperPixel, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKTIFF, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKTestKernel, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKThresholding, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKTransform, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKTransformFactory, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKVNL, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKVNLInstantiation, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKVTK, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKVideoCore, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKVideoFiltering, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKVideoIO, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKVoronoi, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKWatersheds, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Enabled ITKZLIB, requested by ITK_BUILD_DEFAULT_MODULES.
-- Double correction test returned:
-- Checking whether wstring is available
-- Checking whether wstring is available - no
-- Checking whether C compiler has ptrdiff_t in stddef.h
-- Checking whether C compiler has ptrdiff_t in stddef.h - no
-- Checking whether C compiler has ssize_t in unistd.h
-- Checking whether C compiler has ssize_t in unistd.h - no
-- Checking whether C compiler has clock_gettime
-- Checking whether C compiler has clock_gettime - no
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has setenv
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has setenv - no
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has unsetenv
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has unsetenv - no
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has environ in stdlib.h
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has environ in stdlib.h - no
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has utimes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has utimes - no
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has utimensat
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has utimensat - no
-- Checking whether CXX compiler struct stat has st_mtim member
-- Checking whether CXX compiler struct stat has st_mtim member - no
-- Checking whether CXX compiler struct stat has st_mtimespec member
-- Checking whether CXX compiler struct stat has st_mtimespec member - no
-- Looking for include files sys/types.h, ifaddrs.h
-- Looking for include files sys/types.h, ifaddrs.h - not found
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has rlimit64
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has rlimit64 - no
-- Looking for C++ include execinfo.h
-- Looking for C++ include execinfo.h - not found
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has getloadavg
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has getloadavg - no
-- Checking whether <ext/stdio_filebuf.h> is available
-- Checking whether <ext/stdio_filebuf.h> is available - no
-- Performing Test VXL_UNISTD_USLEEP_IS_VOID
-- Performing Test VXL_UNISTD_USLEEP_IS_VOID - Failed
-- Performing Test VCL_HAS_LFS
-- Performing Try-Run Test VCL_HAS_LFS - Test Compilation Failed
-- Performing Test VXL_HAS_DBGHELP_H
-- Performing Test VXL_HAS_DBGHELP_H - Failed
-- Performing Test VXL_PIC_COMPATIBLE
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/itknew/ITK/Modules/ThirdParty/VNL/src/vxl/config/cmake/config/vxl_shared_link_test/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Performing Test VXL_PIC_COMPATIBLE - Success
-- Looking for C++ include emmintrin.h
-- Looking for C++ include emmintrin.h - not found
-- Looking for include file assert.h
-- Looking for include file assert.h - not found
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - not found
-- Looking for include file semaphore.h
-- Looking for include file semaphore.h - not found
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for include file fcntl.h
-- Looking for include file fcntl.h - not found
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h - not found
-- Looking for include file limits.h
-- Looking for include file limits.h - not found
-- Looking for include file malloc.h
-- Looking for include file malloc.h - not found
-- Looking for include file memory.h
-- Looking for include file memory.h - not found
-- Looking for include file search.h
-- Looking for include file search.h - not found
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - not found
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h - not found
-- Looking for include file strings.h
-- Looking for include file strings.h - not found
-- Looking for include file string.h
-- Looking for include file string.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/times.h
-- Looking for include file sys/times.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h - not found
-- Looking for include file unistd.h
-- Looking for include file unistd.h - not found
-- Performing Test VXL_HAS_SSE2_HARDWARE_SUPPORT
-- Performing Try-Run Test VXL_HAS_SSE2_HARDWARE_SUPPORT - Test Compilation Failed
-- Looking for 8-bit int. [Checking char...]
-- Looking for 8-bit int. Not found.
-- Looking for 8-bit int. [Checking short...]
-- Looking for 8-bit int. [Checking char...]
-- Looking for 8-bit int. Not found.
-- Looking for 16-bit int. [Checking char...]
-- Looking for 16-bit int. [Checking int...]
-- Looking for 16-bit int. [Checking short...]
-- Looking for 16-bit int. Not found.
-- Looking for 32-bit int. [Checking short...]
-- Looking for 32-bit int. [Checking long...]
-- Looking for 32-bit int. [Checking int...]
-- Looking for 32-bit int. Not found.
-- Looking for 64-bit int. [Checking __int64...]
-- Looking for 64-bit int. [Checking long long...]
-- Looking for 64-bit int. [Checking long...]
-- Looking for 64-bit int. Not found.
-- Looking for 32-bit float. [Checking long double...]
-- Looking for 32-bit float. [Checking double...]
-- Looking for 32-bit float. [Checking float...]
-- Looking for 32-bit float. Not found.
-- Looking for 64-bit float. [Checking float...]
-- Looking for 64-bit float. [Checking long double...]
-- Looking for 64-bit float. [Checking double...]
-- Looking for 64-bit float. Not found.
-- Looking for 96-bit float. [Checking float...]
-- Looking for 96-bit float. [Checking double...]
-- Looking for 96-bit float. [Checking long double...]
-- Looking for 96-bit float. Not found.
-- Looking for 128-bit float. [Checking float...]
-- Looking for 128-bit float. [Checking double...]
-- Looking for 128-bit float. [Checking long double...]
-- Looking for 128-bit float. Not found.
-- Looking for C++ include unistd.h
-- Looking for C++ include unistd.h - not found
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED - Failed
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - no
-- Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
-- Checking to see if this platform has the __FUNCTION__ C-Preprocessor directive
-- Checking to see if this platform supports has the __FUNCTION__ C-Preprocessor directive - no
-- Looking for include file fenv.h
-- Looking for include file fenv.h - not found
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/itknew/ITK/build/Modules/Core/Common/CMakeTmp/ITK_PRIVATE_DYNAMIC_CAST/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Performing Test ITK_PRIVATE_DYNAMIC_CAST - Failed
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - not found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - not found
-- Looking for memory.h
-- Looking for memory.h - not found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - not found
-- Looking for stdlib.h
-- Looking for stdlib.h - not found
-- Looking for strings.h
-- Looking for strings.h - not found
-- Looking for string.h
-- Looking for string.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - not found
-- Looking for getpagesize
-- Looking for getpagesize - not found
-- Looking for mmap
-- Looking for mmap - not found
-- Looking for getrandom
-- Looking for getrandom - not found
-- Looking for arc4random_buf
-- Looking for arc4random_buf - not found
-- Looking for arc4random
-- Looking for arc4random - not found
-- Looking for 4 include files stdlib.h, ..., float.h
-- Looking for 4 include files stdlib.h, ..., float.h - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSCALL_GETRANDOM
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSCALL_GETRANDOM - Failed
-- Performing Test FLAG_NO_STRICT_ALIASING
-- Performing Test FLAG_NO_STRICT_ALIASING - Failed
-- Performing Test FLAG_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test FLAG_VISIBILITY - Failed
-- Looking for cos in m
-- Looking for cos in m - not found
-- Using CMake version 3.26.0-rc4
-- ZLIB_HEADER_VERSION: 1.2.13
-- ZLIBNG_HEADER_VERSION: 2.1.0.devel
-- Arch detected: 'wasm32'
-- Basearch of 'wasm32' has been detected as: 'wasm32'
-- Using CMake toolchain: C:/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake
-- Performing Test FNO_LTO_AVAILABLE
-- Performing Test FNO_LTO_AVAILABLE - Failed
-- Looking for sys/auxv.h
-- Looking for sys/auxv.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/sdt.h
-- Looking for sys/sdt.h - not found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - not found
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Check size of _off64_t
-- Check size of _off64_t - failed
-- Check size of __off64_t
-- Check size of __off64_t - failed
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - not found
-- Looking for strerror
-- Looking for strerror - not found
-- Looking for posix_memalign
-- Looking for posix_memalign - not found
-- Looking for aligned_alloc
-- Looking for aligned_alloc - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_NO_INTERPOSITION
-- Performing Test HAVE_NO_INTERPOSITION - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY_INTERNAL
-- Performing Test HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY_INTERNAL - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_THREAD_LOCAL
-- Performing Test HAVE_THREAD_LOCAL - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_CTZ
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_CTZ - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_CTZLL
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_CTZLL - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_PTRDIFF_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_PTRDIFF_T - Failed
-- Check size of void *
-- Check size of void * - failed
-- sizeof(void *) is  bytes
CMake Error at Modules/ThirdParty/ZLIB/src/itkzlib-ng/CMakeLists.txt:466 (message):
  sizeof(void *) is neither 32 nor 64 bit


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: I believe with webassebly its supposed to be 32 bit however I am confused how this test failed.

Comment: The error is emitted by [that line](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/Modules/ThirdParty/ZLIB/src/itkzlib-ng/CMakeLists.txt#L466). This code calls `check_type_size("void *" SIZEOF_DATA_PTR)` and then prints value of variable `SIZEOF_DATA_PTR`, which is then checked for 4 and 8. So, what exactly is printed in your case?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have attached the logs. Look it please

Comment: Almost every compiler check is either "not found" or "failed". It cannot find `stdint.h`, it cannot determine size of `void*` (according to [check_type_size](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckTypeSize.html#command:check_type_size) documentation, empty result means that type doesn't exist). Smells like your emscripten toolchain is broken. Have you tried to build any simple project with that toolchain? You could also inspect error messages in `CMakeErrorLog.txt` file. If most of these messages are identical (like "<tool> not found"), then it is a signal of a broken toolchain.

Comment: @Tsyvarev 
when i build helloworld project with `em++ hello.cxx -o example.js` it`s okay

Comment: I meant, have your tried to build any **CMake** project with emscripten toolchain? It could be that toolchain file (`C:/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake`) is improperly configured or so.

Comment: @Tsyvarev no, I didn't try. How can I check if emscripten is working?

Comment: Create any simple CMake project (e.g. [that one](https://coderefinery.github.io/cmake/03-hello-world-cmake/)) and try to configure it with your toolchain (`cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake`). Then you could try build it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it`s okay. It turns out that the matter is in ITK...

Answer (score 1):

ITK has a [WASM package](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK-WASM), so it can definitely compile with Emscripten. Maybe take a look at the code there, and referenced from there.

Comment: I am trying to build ITK source code to be more flexible